# Add random margin to element

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to add a randomly generated margin-left and margin-top values to each element, however within a range.

Between -50px and 0px and 50px. Creating a different staggered and overlapping look each time you refresh

```
<div class="thumbnail" style="margin-top:55px; margin-left: -20px;">
<p>content</p>
</div>

<div class="thumbnail" style="margin-top:-20px; margin-left: 40px; ">
<p>content</p>
</div>

<div class="thumbnail" style="margin-top:70px; margin-left: 2px;">
<p>content</p>
</div>
```

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
function randomMargin(){
    var randomnumber1=Math.floor(Math.random()*101) - 50;
    var randomnumber2=Math.floor(Math.random()*101) - 50;
    $('.thumbnail').css({"margin-top": randomnumber1+"px", "margin-left": randomnumber2+"px"});
}

setInterval(randomMargin, 1000);
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/dnxFn/1/

EDIT for multiple object and a wicked effect:

```
function randomMargin(){
    $('.thumbnail').each(function(){
        randomizeObject(this);

    });

}

function randomizeObject(el){
    var randomnumber1=Math.floor(Math.random()*101) - 50;
    var randomnumber2=Math.floor(Math.random()*101) - 50;
    $(el).css({"margin-top": randomnumber1+"px", "margin-left": randomnumber2+"px"});
}

setInterval(randomMargin, 1000);
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/dnxFn/2/

EDIT -2 this one is the best looking by far http://jsfiddle.net/dnxFn/4/

Comment: @m90 So that i get a number between 0 and 100

Comment: @dzejkej yes of course but after i floor it and so the limit is 100

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti Yes, realized that you are flooring before substracting so I deleted my comment. Thanks! +1 to you for generating a better range :P.

Comment: Wicked effect haha! Thanks @NicolaPeluchetti

Comment: underrated & under appreciated js here

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.thumbnail').each(function() {
  $(this).css({ 
    'margin-top':  Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 - 50) + 'px', 
    'margin-left': Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 - 50) + 'px' });
});
```

**[HERE](http://jsbin.com/enutij/edit#javascript,live)** is the code.

This will set a `margin-top` and `margin-left` styles for each element with the class `thumbnail`. The value returned by [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) is [0, 1), so the calculated numbers will be in range [-50, 50).

**EDIT:** *Nicola Peluchetti* is using `Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) - 50` which will generate numbers in range [-50, 50] (so it can generate also +50px margin). Use that :).